# I can't restore backup from external HD after fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, backup, restore

Before reinstalling, I backed up to not one, but two different hard drives. Reinstalled, updated with software updater, rebooted. 
Connected external hd, opened up backups, selected drive and folder (195 items), but I get an error "No backups to restore" tried the other xhd same thing. What next? I searched Ask and didn't find an answer.

Comment: I made a new backup, same external hd, everything else the same as the original backup I made. Backup worked fine. Then I clicked on restore backup, and got the option to restore the newest backup. Still don't have the option to restore the orginal backup that I really want, the one that has all my files on it.

Comment: What I have found is that there is a process to make an ISO of the install and then restore that ISO rather than using the backup/restore process. PLEASE ADVISE.